# How can I follow qsub's standard error?

Tags: linux, portable-batch-system, torque

I am running a job using torque (qsub).

I would like to follow the standard error of the job as it is being output.

The normal output files (for `stdout` and `stderr`) are only being written once the job finishes.

Is there a way to do something like

```
tail -f /dev/stderr
```

for `stderr` of the submitted job?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `qsub -e /path/to/your/file blah blah blah`

Have a look at [command line args](http://www.adaptivecomputing.com/resources/docs/torque/4-1-2/help.htm#topics/commands/qsub.htm)